# SSIS Derived Column Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image]

I have notificationDate column.
And I want LookUpDate column using derived column in SSIS.

which must look like 12-31-YEAR(NotificationDate)-1
So LookupDate column should be like "12-31-2014" or "12-31-2015"

This is what I am trying to do:

```
 "12" + "-" + "31" + "-" + YEAR( [NotificationDate]  )-1
```

Comment: I want 12-31-YYYY formate, and 12-31 is fixed

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: @EricBrandt its throwing error : Dt_WSTR and DT_I4  are incompatible for binary operator "+"

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to explicitly cast your data types. The expression builder uses it's own syntax for that.

To concatenate a sting to build your date, you'll have to force the year to be a string value. Then, assuming your final output is supposed to be a date again, you'll wrap the whole concatenation in another explicit cast back to date.

This should be pretty close:

```
 (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)("12" + "-" + "31" + "-" + (DT_WSTR, 4)(YEAR(NotificationDate)-1))
```

Comment: just a little modification here, just need to close [NotificationDate] .(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)("12" + "-" + "31" + "-" + (DT_WSTR,4)(YEAR(NotificationDate) - 1)). thanks mate

Comment: Sorry. I dropped a bracket someplace. I took the other one out now. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: And glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

--Please try this.  Make sure Column name you provided here exactly match (case senstive) with source column name

```
(DT_WSTR,6)("12-31-") + (DT_WSTR,4)(YEAR(NotificationDate) - 1)
```